# CV2. Numpy. Как вырезать часть изображения по маске?

Tags: python, изображения, numpy, mask, cv2

Есть изображение RGBA **img_1** преобразованное в массив Numpy размерностью (100, 200, 4). Где 100х200 это размер картинки, 4 - значения RGBA.
Так же имеется маска-массив **mask** в оттенках серого (от 0 до 255) с такой же размерностью (100, 200).
Как создать новый массив/изображение **out** выбирая RGBA из **img_1** по координатам маски, в которой  значения не равны 0?

```
# img_1 оригинальное изображение RGBA сконвертированное в Numpy
img_1 = numpy.array(img_1 )
img_null = numpy.zeros_like(img_1)  # создаем массив из нулей размером (100, 200, 4)
#... здесь фрагмент кода создающий маску с помощью контуров CV2
mask = numpy.array(mask) # маска/массив размерность (100, 200) значения 0-255
out = numpy.where(mask != 0, img_1, img_null) # не работает, из-за несоответствия размерностей
```

Comment: Предполагаю, что нужно использовать срезы, но не могу уловить логику.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод костыльный, но сработал.
Делаем маску в той же размерности (100, 200, 4) и сравниваем срезы.

```
# маску рисуем в формате RGBA
# sort_contours - массив с отсортированными контурами, индекс -1 самый большой 
# контур
cv2.drawContours(mask, [sort_contours[-1]], 0, (255,255,255.0), -1)
# создаем массив для сравнения в маске
null_val = numpy.array([0, 0, 0, 0])
out = numpy.where(mask[:][:] != null_val, img_1[:][:], img_null [:][:])
```

Comment: cv2.boundingRect от маски не пойдет?

Comment: Нет. Так можно зацепить другие окрашенные пиксели, если они будут находиться в прямоугольнике.
Тут именно выборка по маске, типа выделения объекта.
В данном (костыльном) методе в выборку идут только те пикселы/координаты, которые в маске белые.